# How to update a specific(nth) child of a key in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know that Firebase has some very basic query functionality with **orderBy**, **limitTo**, **startAt**, **endAt**...., etc. For updating has methods like **update**, **set**. In my case a i have an structure like this:

[image]

So, there is a list of keys on my **PIN**, how can I update the child **pin** of a specific key with javascript?

For example, I want now to update the **pin** of the second key. Now it has **20**, and I want to set it to **30**. But please, keep in mind that the list most have more than 2 keys, so maybe later I want to update the child **pin** of the fourth generated key.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Relative ordering like "second" or "fourth" are pretty useless here. If you want to update the pin of the node with key `-KrnO...Ho` you can do so with:

```
firebase.database().ref("PIN/`-KrnO...Ho/PIN").set(30);
```

If you want to update the PIN of the user named cindy, you first need to query to determine her key:

```
firebase.database().ref("PIN").orderByChild("name").equalTo("cindy").once("value", function(snapshot) {
  snapshot.forEach(function(user) {
    user.ref.child("PIN").set(30);
  });
})
```

The loop in that second snippet is needed, since there can technically be multiple users named cindy.

Comment: Dear Frank, thanks for your usefull answer. But, I want to know also if there is a way in which I can "_ref_" for "_second_" or "_fourth_" key, regardless (no matter) of the value of the key.

Comment: There is no way to get indexed access without pulling all data down. The "second" node typically has a meaning, which is why I showed how to filter by name.